# discord python timeout . Error: Member.edit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'communication_disabled_until'

Tags: python, discord

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="mute", description="Time out a member in the server.")
@app_commands.describe(member="The member to time out", duration="Time out duration in minutes", reason="Reason for the time out")
@commands.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, duration: int, *, reason: str = "No reason provided"):
    if member.is_timed_out():
        await send_embed(ctx, "Error", f"{member.display_name} is already timed out.")
        return
    
    end_time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=duration)
    
    try:
        await member.edit(communication_disabled_until=end_time, reason=reason)
        await send_embed(ctx, "Success", f"{member.display_name} has been timed out for {duration} minutes. Reason: {reason}")
    except Exception as e:
        await send_embed(ctx, "Error", f"Failed to time out {member.display_name}. Error: {str(e)}")
```

Error
Failed to time out USER. Error: Member.edit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'communication_disabled_until'

i tried communication_disabled_until and timeout but both didnt work

Comment: Try await timed_out_until=end_time instead. You can see parameters to edit function in the docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20edit#discord.Member.edit